# How add association with custom FK in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two models: Users and Microposts. There is an association between `one-to-many`. I would like to add to `Microposts` field `replic_to` and  `replics_from` to `Users`, and association with many-to-many relationships that will not only be stored in the model `Microposts` the author, but the user ID, which is addressed to the message. Because of already having associations between models, I think you need to specify the force field as `FK` for new association. I ask you to show how it can be done. Thank you in advance.

This`s sources:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t| 
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end 
  end 
end

class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t| 
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end 
    add_index(:microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]);
  end 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    has_many(:microposts, dependent: :destroy);
    ....
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    belongs_to :user;
    ....
end
```

Comment: look at the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html different options for `has_many`/`belongs_to` (for example chapter "2.10 Self Joins")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to micropost.rb

```
belongs_to :replics_to, class_name: 'User'
```

The corresponding field should be

```
add_column :microposts, :replics_to_id, :integer
```

For user.rb

```
has_many :replics_from, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'replics_to_id'
```